# Execute git pull as sudo -u user

Tags: git, ssh, cron

I am kind of stumped by the behavior of `git pull`.

My User is called `tom` and when I run

```sh
$ whoami
tom
$ git pull
```

everything works fine.
But when I run

```sh
$ sudo -u tom git pull
```

I get the following error:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Shouldn't the two runs be exactly the same? Why do they behave differently?

**EDIT: Solution**
As pointed out by Torek below, the answer was to do `sudo -u tom -E git pull` to pass the environment variables including the information for the SSH agent through.

Comment: the rights on your computer are not the same rights of your remote

Comment: try adding `-i` to your sudo command : `sudo -i -u tom git pull`

Comment: Thanks @LeGEC, but I get the following error
`$ sudo -i -u tom git pull
> fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set)`

Comment: ah right ... `sudo -i` will place you in your `$HOME` directory.

Comment: Ah that makes sense.
but even when I write a script that goes to the right folder it still fails even with `sudo -i -u tom`

Comment: ok, then that was a bad guess. To debug your issue, you may try to compare `ssh -v git@github.com` with `sudo -u tom ssh -v git@github.com`.

Comment: Are you using an ssh agent? If so, note that there won't be one in place for either the `sudo` job or the cron job. (If you let sudo pass the agent identity through, you can get that for the interactive session, but it still won't be in place when using cron.)

Comment: Ah that's a good point @torek. How can I pass the ssh-agent to the sudo command?

Comment: @T.Kau: You can use `-E` (aka `--preserve-env`) to pass environment variables through. But there still won't be any agent in place when running cron jobs.

Comment: Yes that finally worked, thanks torek!